# Is there static block in class in python

Tags: python, static, block

I am relatively new to python
I would like to run a block of code only once for a class. Like the static block in java.

for eg:

```
class ABC:
    execute this once for a class.
```

Is there any such options available in python?

In java we write it like this. This is executed only once for a class, at the time the class is loaded. Not for every object creation

```
public class StaticExample{
    static {
        System.out.println("This is first static block");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you not want to put your code in the `__init__` function?

Comment: I guess no. __init__ gets called on each object creation. I need it to execute it only once.

Comment: @root45: that would get called once per *instance* of the class.  M S is asking for something that gets called once per class.

Comment: @Cpfohl that's what I thought, but I thought I'd clarify.

Comment: Did you try what you have typed in the question? What happened?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To do this just put the code directly under the class definition (parallel to the function definitions for the class.

All code directly in the class gets executed upon creation of that type in the class' namespace.  Example:

```
class Test:
    i = 3
    y = 3 * i
    def testF(self):
        print Test.y

v = Test()
v.testF()
# >> 9
```

Just to fill out the last bit of information for you: your method function `def`s are also being executed (just like they get "executed" when you define a function on the global namespace), but they aren't called. It just happens to be that executing a `def` has no obviously visible results.

Python's object-oriented-ness is quite clever, but it takes a bit to get your head around it! Keep it up, it's a very fun language.

Comment: Please do not access static variable / class variable with self.y use. At least use Test.y instead

Comment: Huh, never noticed that I did that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     print "static block was executed"
... 
static block was executed
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>>
```

See here for more information about static variables/functions in Python: [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)